# can you add a style an arrangement in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

Hello I have been working in app inventor whilst teaching and Im having problems with the styling. For someone who spends her days as a front end developer not being able to change css or html is killing me. I need to see if I can change the colour of a Layout is this possible ?

Kind Regards

Comment: include your tried code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you do not have much formatting possibilities in **App Inventor**. You can adjust the screen background color or use a screen background image, but you can't adjust the color of a horizontal, vertical or table arrangement. Unfortunately there is nothing like css available. only the `notifier` offers some more formatting functionality, see also [here](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2notifier).

Alternatively you might want to use the `webviewer` instead together with locally stored html pages. [How to read a HTML page stored as asset inside of App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2htmlread).
See also some more examples [here](https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#html).